# How to make an executable program from AppleScript

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, applescript, executable

In order to run my AppleScript program I have to open it up and select "run." I want the program to just run when I click on it. I tried to compile it, but it didn't seem to make a difference or create a new file.

Answer (score 22):

2 ways.

1) my preferred method is to activate the Script menu. If you're using 10.6, open AppleScript Editor. Open the preferences and under the General tab click "Show Script menu in Menu Bar". Now you'll get a new icon in the menu bar section at the top-right of your screen. You can run any applescript from that menu. (in 10.5 the process is different but you can google for directions). To put an applescript in that menu just go to the folder ~/Library/Scripts and add your applescript to it. Choosing your applescript from the Script menu will run it.

2) "Save As..." from the file menu in AppleScript Editor and set the "File Format" to application. Then it works like any other application... just double-click it to run it.

NOTE: if you use the Script menu... selecting a script will run it. If you want to instead open the script in AppleScript Editor for editing then hold the option key down while choosing the script.

Comment: Please note: it's AppleScript editor, not Automator.

Answer (score 7):

When you are saving your AppleScript, you can choose to save it as an application, which will make it executable.

Comment: If the script file already exist you may not get the Save As option (only Save), in which case you may have to trick it by selecting duplicate. Then you will get the dialog for the file format.

Comment: You can also File->export as an app

Comment: It is worth mentioning that a 133-byte script is saved as a 101-kbyte application :[.

Answer (score 3):

If you were considering methods like the first one mentioned by regulus6633 you can launch AppleScripts with Quicksilver, TextExpander, osascript and some other. To make an application you just use the method 2.

Answer (score -1):

A clickable app if saved properly:

```
# Old post but this answer may save someone a lot of time.
# In Applescript, make a new script with the following lines (see below).
# Then, after selecting the ''Stay open after run handler'' option,
# save as File Format ''application'' .
# This is the simplest version of a standalone app.
# It is essentially a directory with a Scripts folder and a compiled Applet in it.
# Right click it's icon in the Finder to open the package for a peek inside.
# Other internal items such as icons, files, and other scripts may be added and interacted with.

on run
    #put something here which happens once at startup.
    say "I am running."
end run

on idle
    #put something here which happens repeatedly.
    say "I am waiting."
    return 2 --repeats every 2 seconds. (0 will default to 30 seconds)
end idle

on quit
    #put something here which happens at the end of the program's use.
    say "I am quitting."
    continue quit
end quit

# To accept dropped item's, embed your handlers between tags before saving as shown below here. Enjoy! 

on open droppedItems
    beep --or some other cool thing.
end open
```

Comment: The OP simply wanted to know how to save his **AppleScript** _script_, that by default is saved as a **.scpt** _file_, as an _application_ so it wouldn't continually open in **Script Editor** and have to click **Run**. -- **Not how to structure his already working _code_!**

Comment: It doesn't replace the OP's code, it's a wrapper for any code the OP wants to run as an app. The sections beginning with "#put something here..." are where to put the OP's existing code. The "run", "Idle", and "Quit" handlers are Apple's standard way of converting Applescripts into runnable apps as in the OP's 2 requirements "run my AppleScript program" & " just run when I click on it". The OP's code gets inserted into one of the handlers (or put into the automatically generated "Scripts" folder inside the app package). That's literally "How to make an executable program from AppleScript".

Comment: The 3 basic ways an Applescript can run are: [1] in Script Editor, [2] in the osascript app (menu bar's Script menu), [3] as applet with extension ".app". To save applescripts as click-to-run applications they need a run handler. If you want one to stay running, it needs an idle handler. If you want it to quit then it needs a quit handler. All 3 are included in my answer. As this can run silently in the backround, I added speech to prove it was working, otherwise the OP would not know if the app was functional. It can then be dragged to the Dock and run there too since now it's a real app!